# emacs dired時の親ディレクトリへ、あるいはファイル編集時のカレントディレクトリーへ移動

Tags: emacs

ファイルを編集している時のカレントディレクトリへ、そしてdiredの時は親ディレクトリー移動も同じキーボード操作でディレクトリー(dired)移動したいのですが方法はありますか？

現在は、ファイル編集時はC-xd を2回続けることで、ディレクトリー(dired)の時は `..` をエンターすることでディレクトリー移動しています。
あるいはC-xbでバッファーリストからの移動等の操作でやっています。
よろしくお願いします。

emacs バージョン 25.2.1

Comment: ファイルの親ディレクトリとは何？ `/home/alice/daily/example.c` を編集中にどこに行きたいっスか？

Comment: 参考までに、`dired` には `dired-jump` という関数があります(デフォルトで `C-x C-j` に bind)。dired mode の場合は親ディレクトリに移動しますが、通常ファイルの場合には、そのファイルがあるディレクトリに移動します。

Comment: >>/home/alice/daily/example.c を編集中..        /home/alice/daily/です。

Comment: dired-jump 初めて知りました。ネットを結構調べたつもりだったのですが、わかりませんでした。この操作で解決です。どうもありがとうございました。(もっと早く質問すればよかった・・・独り言)

Comment: @nagao `/home/alice/daily/example.c` を編集中は `/home/alice/daily/` は **カレント** ディレクトリであり、親ディレクトリは `/home/alice/` になりませんか？

Comment: 仰る通りだと思います。すいません、不適切な言い方でした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

※ 質問のコメント欄から書き写し

dired には `dired-jump` という関数があります(デフォルトで <kbd>C-x C-j</kbd> に bind)。dired mode の場合は親ディレクトリに移動しますが、通常ファイルの場合には、そのファイルがあるディレクトリに移動します。

Comment: こういうご時世出かけるわけにも行かず(実際は持病がある事の方が要因大ですが)
定年後、趣味として、CUIモードの自宅サーバで、rails, javascript等をガチャガチャ
我流でやっています。
emacs はたぶん機能の一部しか利用できてないかもしれないが重宝する代物です。
どうもありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

**補足:**
M-x dired-jump 後はC-x C-j のキーボード操作は良かったのですが、そうで無いときは効かなかったので下記の設定をinit.elに入れました。

**~/.emacs.d/init.el**

```
(define-key global-map "\C-x\C-j" 'dired-jump)
```

指摘を受けた様に、この方が良いように思えます。多分diredの他の機能
も使えるのでは

```
(require 'dired-x)
```

参考：
[emacs - Emacs; dired、dired-xをロードする前のC-x C-j](https://cloud6.net/so/emacs/3302160)

Comment: `(require 'dired-x)` とするだけで `C-x C-j` 効くと思うのだけれども。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。